# Shared part of game logic on server and client

Tags: networking, server, client, client-server, solid

I am creating online collection card game. I have game logic on my server. But this part of code contains concepts which need on server and client. For example HexVector, HexSlot, some enums etc. Player can click on game field and I have to send position(HexVector) from client to server.

Where do I need to store HexVector? Should I create shared project in submodule for server and client which will contains only things like HexVector, or I need to have game logic submodule in server and client? Client will be use only the things it need and server will be use all game logic.

Comment: What technology are you using?

Comment: C#, LiteNetLib, Unity

Answer (score 0):

Never belive player. You don't know how he can use this part of code. So I decide to separate common game logic in separated submodule.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).